# Copiar dados de uma planilha com filtro usando VBA

Tags: vba, filtro

Preciso criar uma macro para fazer um filtro, copiar o resultado desse filtro a partir da 2ª linha e colar em outra sheet. Já tentei de tudo (offset, usedrange, sendkeys) porém nada deu certo.
Eu preciso que seja variável por que a posição do range vai mudar sempre que eu atualizar a base com novas informações. Esse é o último código que eu tentei:

```
Sheets("Pendências").Select
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$419655").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="1"
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("HEX Acima").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```